# duplicated stroke

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

when I stroke in sculpt mode it does a second identical one there's a second dot as well showing me where the identical line
this second line/dot is always on the opposite side of the sculpture does anyone know how i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Look under the tab that says "Symmetry" (In the Active Tool and Workspace Settings) - you'll see mirroring on the X axis is enabled by default

[image: Mirror]